# Page appears centered at 120% zoom but on the left at 100%

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

As the question says, if I'm zoomed to 120% on MS Word 2010 it looks like this:

[image]

But as soon as I drop down to 110% it looks like this (100% shown in image)

[image]

As you can see from the images I am on Print Layout. What setting do I have to change to get this back to normal (i.e. always centered)?

btw if I click on that One Page button in the View tab then it centers but at 75% zoom, as soon as I try zoom in or out it jumps back the the left.

I want it to be centered by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old Thread but for people still looking a Solution.

Click the Review Tab, and set tracking to "No Markup"

[image: No_markup]

Comment: Thanks for answering, I have no idea if this works as I can't replicate the issue anymore. But I'll accept it on faith :)

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by the use of wide screen monitors. There is an easy way to center it without increasing the zoom.

---

On the view tab, click `Web Layout`.

[image]

Now click on the `Print Layout` again.

[image]

Comment: But how do I make this the default behaviour? If I do this, then I can zoom with the mouse wheel (holding control) and it stays centered, but if I click on that zoomy bar in the bottom right then it reverts back to the left.

Comment: From what I've found, I don't think you can. You could probably write a macro to run on open to do it for you.

Comment: A colleague has the identical screens to me, same resolution, but his is centered by default.

Comment: I did the above on a blank document and closed it. Now it centers automatically when I open a new document. Saved documents may have views saved and need to be adjusted.

Comment: just tried that. No good for me I'm afraid :(

Answer (score 0):

As someone said this is caused by wide screen monitors. I had 20Inch dell first & the blank new page was centered perfectly at 100% zoom. When I purchased a 21.5Inch monitor it aligns to left at 100% Zoom print layout. The above solution switching to web layout and back to print layout did not help for me. What I did was increase the Zoom level at the bottom tight to 104% it remains at center. If anyone have other default solution please come up
KR Dasharathi